# Optimizing for Same Keyword in 2 Different Regions (US & Canada) - Yes or No?

Tags: seo, url, international

**Background:** The same company is operating in 2 regions (US & CANADA). The language is fairly similar except for slight content differences, however, the primary keyword is the same, after evaluating keyword opportunities.

Canada URL is: website.io
US URL is: website.io/us/

**Question:** Is this considered 'keyword cannibalization', even though I'm trying to rank in different regions? If so, what is the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't be considered keyword cannibalization. It's perfectly OK and SEO friendly to target the same keyword for multiple regions(provided it's the best choice for that particular region).